# StreamWriter to multiple files

Tags: c#, streamwriter

OK, so I received an answer that I am not asking the question correctly.  It is not writing each line to the text files.  It is not writing anything at all.  It build successfully when run, but nothing is written out with StreamWriter.  I am not sure what I I am doing wrong with my questions.  If this is not the correct way to ask the question, can someone tell me how to ask the question?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = @"C:/Users/cswenson/Desktop/TestProgram/test.txt";
            var outputp = @"C:/Users/cswenson/Desktop/TestProgram/preout.txt";
            var outputm1 = @"C:/Users/cswenson/Desktop/TestProgram/match1.txt";
            var outputm2 = @"C:/Users/cswenson/Desktop/TestProgram/match2.txt";


            using (var sr = new StringReader(input))
            using (var psw = new StreamWriter(outputp, true))
            using (var o1sw = new StreamWriter(outputm1, true))
            using (var o2sw = new StreamWriter(outputm2, true))
            {
               foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(input))
                {
                    string preout = line.Substring(1, 8) + " " + line.Substring(374, 329) + " " + line.Substring(4937, 639);
                    psw.WriteLine(preout);
                    string match1 = line.Substring(1, 8) + " " + line.Substring(9, 365) + " " + line.Substring(703, 1786);
                    o1sw.WriteLine(match1);
                    string match2 = line.Substring(1, 8) + " " + line.Substring(2489, 2448);
                    o2sw.WriteLine(match2);

                }


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have with your code. What is happening, what are the problems and what do you want instead?

Comment: I recommend you take a step back and learn how to debug your code at run time. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: You can inspect the values of your variables real time and run code snippits in the IDE at run time to see "what would happen if...". That will allow you to fix your own problem(s).... whatever they might be.

Comment: `using (var sr = new StringReader(input))` looks suspicious... =)

Comment: For simple debugging, use `Console.WriteLine()` to output the values for `line`, `preout`, `match1` and `match2`. Also include a counter variable so you can see which line you are processing. Then [edit] your question to include the outputs you get with these debug lines.

Comment: What is the `sr` variable for? It appears to never be used (and thus will likely block the later `File.ReadLines`).

Comment: The line 'using (var sr = new StringReader(input))' is unnecessary. The input file ("C:/Users/cswenson/Desktop/TestProgram/test.txt")  probably doesn't contain any contents.

Comment: Thank you everyone!  I really appreciate the input.  I was able to double check everything and using StringReader instead of StreamReader was the issue.  It is working now.  Thanks again, I really appreciate the help!